# Java project from existing ant build file doesn't appear as in version control

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant, project

I have a repository in which I have a simple ant project (only the src directory and the build.xml file). I did a checkout of this project in a local copy. Then I opened Eclipse, created a "Java Project from existing Ant build file" and it worked fine. I can build, clean, run, generate javadocs, etc. However, my problem is that the source files in the packages, as well as the project itself, doesn't appear to be under version control in Eclipse. I can work with it fine from Cygwin, but not from the GUI.

The odd thing is that I have several regular Java projects, on the same repository which are synced fine by Eclipse, so it's not a version issue.

When I created the projects that work, I had to go to Team->Share Project... and Eclipse told me that they were already under version control and updated its configuration. However, in this current case, this isn't working. Any suggestion please?

#### EDIT:

I'm using svn 1.8.

UPDATE: I tried creating a regular Java project, and this time the version control looks fine, so it appears it's an issue related only to Java Project from Existing Ant build file.

Comment: When you got your local copy of the simple ant project, did you do a checkout or an export? You can tell by the presence of the .svn files and folders. If there are no .svn assets you won't be able to 'Share Project'.

Comment: @radimpe Actually, I did an update, since I already had a local copy of the repo and I just added a new directory in it. I was under the impression that, since svn 1.7, there was only one .svn folder, in the root of the local copy, and not in every sub-directory. I find it odd to see Eclipse fail like this, when Netbeans works fine.

Comment: @radimpe Also, I don't have the .svn folders in the other Java projects that work.

Comment: I still have loads of them and I'm on 1.7.x.

Comment: Try deleting the .project file and import again. Maybe it got corrupted. I've done that in the past and it worked.

Comment: @radimpe I've tried creating and recreating them 3-4 times, no luck. Also, I've done a checkout on the exact ant project directory (the one that has the src and build.xml) so now I have a .svn folder there. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't know your project is using Subversion as a version control tool. You did a checkout *outside* of Eclipse, then you set up Eclipse as if this was a non-version controlled project.

To get Eclipse to recognize the project as under Subversion, you need to let Eclipse know. This means you should have said "File->New->Project, and select SVN->Checkout Project from SVN in the new project wizard. Then, Eclipse would have checked the project out in Subversion for you, and Eclipse would understand this project is in Subversion.

Unfortunately, I am not quite familiar enough with Eclipse to know how to tell Eclipse that the current project is really under version control. The best I could come up with was:

- Right-click on the project and select Team->Share
- Say this is a Subversion project you want to share.
- Select the Repository to use
- Select the folder where you want this project, and select the current folder.

You get the following warning:

> Warning: The specified folder already exists in the repository. If you continue, that folder will be checked out to the existing location. Do you want to continue?

Your project will now be "checked out" over your current project. Everything ***should*** be okay because the files you have either match what is in Subversion or are modified versions of what is in Subversion.

You will be then asked to use the Synchronized view. Check "Yes", and then switch back to the Java view. Eclipse will now know your project is under Subversion and everything should work fine.

Note the use of ***Shoulds*** and ***Coulds***. This is my way of saying that the advise given is done on an "as is" basis and I am not responsible for any damage done by following this advice, so please don't sue me.

It's basically your standard open source license.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I won't sue you... THIS TIME! Kidding, nothing happened. I have tried both ways and this is what it happened: When trying to Checkout project from SVN, I selected that I want a new Java Project from Existing Ant build file. However, it then asked to select the build file that didn't exist, since the checkout wasn't done yet. Not to mention that it would have probably checked out the code in the workspace rather than my SVN folder.

Comment: When trying to go with Team->Share, I can see the sources from the src dir in the project under revision control, but the same sources in the package tree view aren't... I'm at a loss.